# Binary representation of a double

Tags: c++

I was bored and wanted to see what the binary representation of double's looked like. However, I noticed something weird on windows. The following lines of codes demonstrate

```
double number = 1;
unsigned long num = *(unsigned long *) &number;
cout << num << endl;
```

On my Macbook, this gives me a nonzero number. On my Windows machine it gives me 0.

I was expecting that it would give me a non zero number, since the binary representation of 1.0 as a double should not be all zeros. However, I am not really sure if what I am trying to do is well defined behavior.

My question is, is the code above just stupid and wrong? And, is there a way I can print out the binary representation of a double?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure, it was an Intel Macbook? Anyway, verify by printing the value of sizeof(unsigned long) on both machines / compilers. Anyway, for reliable result, cast to char pointer and do a hex dump to see the bytes.

Comment: Check out http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 double is [`3ff0 0000 0000 0000`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). `long` is a [4 byte int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). On a [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) hardware you're reading the `0000 0000` part.

Comment: `long` in Microsoft's compiler is 32-bit. but `long` is a 64-bit value on Linux/MacOS if the OS is 64-bit. Which could also explain the difference...

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports it (GCC does) then use a union. This is undefined behavior according to the C++ standard (strict aliasing rule):

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    union {
        unsigned long long num;
        double fp;
    } pun;

    pun.fp = 1.0;
    std::cout << std::hex << pun.num << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
3ff0000000000000
```