# Does the implementation of pow() function in C/C++ vary with platform or compiler?

Tags: c++, precision, terminology, pow

It took a day to debug the built-in `pow()` function's output. The output  differed between my compiler and an online compiler. That is a long story. I have written the following  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproduce the situation.

#### Code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// This function just prints the binary representation as it is in memory
// A modified version of Lightness Races in Orbit's code given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37861479/3555000
// I thank Lightness Races in Orbit for the contribution
void print_binary(long double y)
{
    const long double x = y;
    unsigned char     a[sizeof(long double)];

    copy(
        reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&x),
        reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&x) + sizeof(long double),
        &a[0]
    );
    for (auto el : a)
    {
        bitset<8>k(el);
        cout << k.to_string() ;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {20,29,31}, res=0; //Took three numbers and initialized the result
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout<<"i = "<<i<< ", a["<<i<< "] = "<<a[i]<<"\npow(" << a[i] <<","<<i+1 << "):\nBinary: ";
        long double temp = pow(a[i],i+1);
        print_binary(temp);
        res+=temp;
        cout<<setprecision(50)<<fixed<< "Decimal: " <<temp <<", Result = "<<res<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output in my Code::Blocks:

```
i = 0, a[0] = 20
pow(20,1):
Binary: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010000000000011010000000110100000000000
Decimal: 20.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, Result = 20
i = 1, a[1] = 29
pow(29,2):
Binary: 111111011111111111111111111111111111111111111111001111111101001000001000010000000110100000000000
Decimal: 840.99999999999999983346654630622651893645524978637695, Result = 860
i = 2, a[2] = 31
pow(31,3):
Binary: 111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111011110100000001101010000000110100000000000
Decimal: 29790.99999999999999644728632119949907064437866210937500, Result = 30650
```

#### Output in [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Gizghz):

```
i = 0, a[0] = 20
pow(20,1):
Binary: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010000000000011010000000000000000000000
Decimal: 20.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, Result = 20
i = 1, a[1] = 29
pow(29,2):
Binary: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000001101001000001000010000000000000000000000
Decimal: 841.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, Result = 861
i = 2, a[2] = 31
pow(31,3):
Binary: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101111101110100000001101010000000000000000000000
Decimal: 29791.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, Result = 30652
```

I thought that `pow()` function gives wrong output sometimes, but the implementation of it is the same in all compilers. Because I thought it has an established standard.

#### My Questions:

- Does the implementation of `pow()` function in C/C++ vary with platform or compiler?
- Isn't there any established standard for `pow()` function?
- What do I call this error? (Say, Undefined behavior)

Comment: [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945815/math-precision-requirements-of-c-and-c-standard

Comment: Even more fun: on the same compiler there can be subtle differences between `pow` and `std::pow`. I've never been able to figure out why. By the way,  `#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` exposes you to unnecessary risk. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: I notice you took my code from your previous question (without attribution), and made it worse. (a) [Don't use that "bits" header](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648); (b) Don't write `using namespace std;` (c) Don't use `bitset<8>` for this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit At first I did not notice it as it makes almost no importance here. But later I noticed it and started to preparing how I can attribute you. I am extremely sorry. I did not ask your original name. Can you please tell me your name?

Comment: @manetsus: My name is "Lightness Races in Orbit". The attribution is right now, thank you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Really? Is it actually your name? Then what would be your nickname? I don't believe! However, you are welcome and sorry again. :)

Comment: You may be interested in this [Q & A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa) too.

Comment: That least-significant-bit down-round on integer results really chaps my hide.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of factors affect the result of floating-point arithmetic, such as rounding, order of the operations. Even using same code of `pow()`, different hardware, different compilers or even different compiling options may give different results, that's why binary comparison is meaningless.

There's standard on `std::pow` and floating point numbers.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

But as pointed by some of the question comments, the standard does not specify everything and compiler/code sometimes does not even follow the standard. Most of the time, it's a balance between precision and speed.

Numerical error / floating-point precision error / accuracy error - not sure. Undefined behavior is usually unexpected and far away from correct. But all results from different pow() are correct.

Comment: Isn't there any established standard for pow() function? What do I call this error?

Comment: @Eric `-ffast-math` does not make any change in my code. Thanks

Comment: OK. That may not affect the compiled library. This may be interesting. https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl/vm/functions/_accuracyall.html

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply, the C++ standard explicitly imposes no requirements on the accuracy of floating-point operations or the numeric library functions like `std::pow`. They are *implementation-specific.*

The various standard library implementations<sup>1</sup> (glibc, musl, etc.) can and do use different approximations of numeric functions. Here are a few implementations of `pow` for example:

- [libm](https://github.com/bminor/musl/blob/7ada6dde6f9dc6a2836c3d92c2f762d35fd229e0/src/math/pow.c#L255) and [glibc](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/520b1df08de68a3de328b65a25b86300a7ddf512/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_pow.c#L282) currently use the same implementation contributed by ARM, which claims worst-case error of 0.54 ULP.
- [glibc's previous (before Sep 2018) implementation](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/dab9c3488e86d5304f3e4b778933760374494a82/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_pow.c#L59) contributed by IBM, which claims to be correctly rounded.
- [fdlibm](https://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_pow.c) from Sun Microsystems, "nearly rounded."
- [crlibm](https://github.com/taschini/crlibm/blob/eb3063791aa75bc9705b49283bf14250465220a7/pow.c#L767), correctly rounded.

If you need deterministic behavior, you need to use the same standard library on all platforms/with all compilers.

---

<sup>1</sup>Not to be confused with compiler or platform. Usually the standard library is provided by the compiler, but not necessarily.

Answer (score -3):

First thing I'd like to point out is that you are using res to print out your result, you are also adding result together multiple times in the loop, meaning by the second iteration  your result is wrong.

Move res = 0 into the for loop.

Comment: It is just getting cumulative result. Whats wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing. Joel misunderstood the question and the code.